# Rebased onto remote and changes are missing; what happened?

Tags: git

I had a problem today, and I still can't figure out what happened.

I wanted to get changes from a remote, and rebase onto it. This was all in the same branch, let's say `dev` for arguments sake:

```
a --- b --- c --- e <-- local/dev

a --- b --- c --- d <-- remote/dev
```

I figured that the way to do this is to do:

```
git fetch
git checkout dev
git rebase remote/dev
```

I was fairly sure I'd done that in the past. The result I would expect there would be:

```
a --- b --- c --- d --- e
```

The commit messages appeared to backup that this was indeed the state of the history, however, **the changes which were contained in `e` were no longer present**. I've not been able to explain this, neither have I been able to understand it any further by searching the internet.

It may be that I did not follow the steps as I outlined above, or it may be that there must be other factors to explain what happened.  I suppose my question is, **is what happened above normal, or must there be other circumstances to explain it?**

Perhaps a `git pull --rebase` is the better option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be some other circumstances.  (I have no guess as to what they might be.)

> Perhaps a `git pull --rebase` is the better option here.

That does the same thing.  Your original command sequence is `git checkout dev` plus the command-pair `git fetch; git rebase`.  What `git pull` does is run `git fetch` followed by a second Git command, usually `git merge` but `git pull --rebase` runs `git rebase` second.  Hence:

```
git checkout dev; git pull --rebase
```

is the same as:

```
git checkout dev; git fetch; git rebase
```

It's just four characters shorter (including the semicolons and spaces).

#### Recovering from a bad rebase

Note that your original commit(s) are still available in your repository.  To find them, use one of these two mechanisms:

- `ORIG_HEAD`: this is a marker that multiple different commands set before making any changes.  If the last thing you did that made changes was `git rebase`, `ORIG_HEAD` will be whatever the rebase saved before making changes.  (The other commands that set it are `git am`, `git reset`, and—sometimes—`git merge`, when it does a fast-forward operation instead of doing a merge.)
- The *reflog* for `HEAD`.  This stores multiple previous values of `HEAD`.  Each one is numbered and time-stamped.  Old entries eventually expire: Git makes sure this does not happen before at least 30 or 90 days by default.  It's a little tricky to explain what's going on here without another very useful piece of background information.

  (For the background, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).  What's really going on is that *reachable* reflog entries—reachable from the current value of the reference, that is—have a 90 day expiration by default, while *unreachable*-from-the-ref entries have a 30 day expiration by default.  Both are tunable, and the special `refs/stash` reference has a different default: stash reflog entries never expire, by default.)

Except for the facts that there's only one `ORIG_HEAD`, and that reflog entries expire based on *time* rather than by being overwritten by the next value stored into `ORIG_HEAD`, these two things work pretty much the same way.

To see commits from `ORIG_HEAD`, use `git log ORIG_HEAD` (or the same with additional options).  To see commits that are in the reflog, use `git reflog show` or `git log -g` (`git reflog show` actually invokes `git log -g` so you can pass additional `git log` options to `git reflog`).

#### Example

Let's look at a rebase that has gone wrong for some reason—most typically, a rebase that requires fixing too many merge conflicts.  We'll start with the command-sequence that kicks it all off, but spell it like this to be explicit:

```
git checkout dev && git fetch && git rebase
```

The `git checkout dev` command gets us onto the branch we would like to rebase.  The `git fetch` step fills in `origin/dev`, and the `git rebase` command starts the rebase, which will copy the commits that are on our `dev` that are not on our `origin/dev`.  The `&&`s make sure that each command finishes successfully before the next command starts—semicolons would run the next command even if the previous one failed.

The copies will go after the commit to which `origin/dev` points.  That is, after `git fetch`, we might have this commit graph in our repository:

```
...--o--o--A--B--C   <-- dev (HEAD)
         \
          E--F   <-- origin/dev
```

What we'd like to end up with is this:

```
...--o--o--A--B--C   [abandoned]
         \
          E--F   <-- origin/dev
              \
               A'-B'-C'  <-- dev (HEAD)
```

where `A'` is our copy of `A`, `B'` is our copy of `B`, and `C'` is our copy of `C`.

If everything works—or at least, if *Git thinks* everything worked—the rebase ends with this:

```
...--o--o--A--B--C   <-- ORIG_HEAD, dev@{1}
         \
          E--F   <-- origin/dev
              \
               A'-B'-C'  <-- dev
```

The `ORIG_HEAD` setting gets done after the rebase finishes.  The `dev@{1}` is the reflog entry for `dev` after the rebase finishes.  (Note that as we do other commands, entry #1 gets pushed down to entry #2, #3, and so on, so you must check, with `git reflog show` or equivalent, what the number is *now* if it's not right-after-finished.)

If you've finished the rebase, and run `git log` or view the result or run your tests or whatever and are horrified and want to put things back, you can now run:

```
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

or:

```
git reset --hard dev@{1}
```

Both of these will:

- locate the specified commit, which is whatever the actual hash is for commit `C`;
- make the name `dev` point to this commit (pushing the reflog entries down one in the process); and
- re-set the index and work-tree as well (because of the `--hard`) so that the index and work-tree now match commit `C`.

Note that `git reset` will make `ORIG_HEAD` point where `HEAD` did a moment ago.  That is, we'll now have:

```
...--o--o--A--B--C   <-- dev (HEAD), dev@{2}
         \
          E--F   <-- origin/dev
              \
               A'-B'-C'  <-- ORIG_HEAD, dev@{1}
```

A plain `git log`, which starts from `HEAD` and works backwards, will now show us commit `C`, then `B`, then `A`, then the rightmost `o`, and so on.

Suppose, on the other hand, that we *start* the rebase, and have gotten to this point:

```
...--o--o--A--B--C   <-- dev
         \
          E--F   <-- origin/dev
              \
               A'-B'  <-- HEAD
```

We're in the middle of the rebase, trying to cherry-pick commit `C` to make `C'`, and have hit a bunch of conflicts.  We look at the conflicts and decide: *It's not time to do this after all.*  We'd like to go back to how things were before we started.

The `git status` command will tell us that we are in "detached HEAD" mode, in the middle of a rebase.  We run:

```
git rebase --abort
```

which will stop our rebase and re-check-out `dev` for us, giving us this:

```
...--o--o--A--B--C   <-- dev (HEAD)
         \
          E--F   <-- origin/dev
              \
               A'  <-- HEAD@{2}
                \
                 B'  <-- HEAD@{1}
```

This time, I've drawn in the `HEAD` reflog entries that remember commits `A'` and `B'`.  These always exist—we just leave them out of the graph drawings most of the time, as reflog entries are usually invisible.  This is true for `ORIG_HEAD` as well: we leave it out when we don't care about it, because `git log` does not look at it unless we call for it explicitly.

#### Another example

Suppose you think you have finished your rebase, but either quit it (`git rebase --quit`, a relatively new option) or are actually still in the middle of it, with conflicts.  In this case, you should *first run `git status`* to make sure things are the way you think they are:

```
git status
```

If this tells you that you are in the middle of a rebase, you have the option of finishing the rebase or aborting it, as in the example above.

If you really are done, you can use `git reflog` to find any partial cherry-picks that succeeded, and make a new temporary branch pointing to this.  For instance, suppose we successfully made `A'` and `B'` as before, saw the conflicts for `C'`, and accidentally terminated the rebase with `git rebase --abort`.  We put a lot of work into resolving conflicts with `A'` and `B'` and want them back.  Now we run:

```
git reflog
```

to find `HEAD@{1}`, `HEAD@{2}`, and so on, to verify that we really do have:

```
...--o--o--A--B--C   <-- dev (HEAD)
         \
          E--F   <-- origin/dev
              \
               A'  <-- HEAD@{2}
                \
                 B'  <-- HEAD@{1}
```

Since `B'` is valuable, let's give it a new branch name, e.g., `new-dev`:

```
git checkout -b new-dev HEAD@{1}
```

and now we have this graph, which we'll draw without the `HEAD@{...}` parts:

```
...--o--o--A--B--C   <-- dev
         \
          E--F   <-- origin/dev
              \
               A'-B'  <-- new-dev (HEAD)
```

and we can get back to work as normal.  Eventually we can make `dev` point to commit `B'` or a new `C'` or whatever we choose; but for now, we're good to work on `new-dev` while keeping `dev` around.

#### Main points to remember

- Commits are mostly-permanent and completely-unchangeable.  Their true name is their big ugly hash ID, but those are impossible for humans to remember and deal with, so we give them names.  They stick around as long as they are *reachable* (see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/)).
- Branch *names* are human-readable identifiers that hold hash IDs.  *We* choose the names; *Git* chooses their values (the hash IDs of the underlying commits).  The current branch name's value gets updated automatically whenever we make *new* commits.  Each name points to the *last* commit that Git should show when we `git log` the branch, and *the* commit that Git should *check out* when we `git checkout` the branch.
- Using `git checkout` with a branch name attaches the name `HEAD` to one of the branch names, so that new commits will update that branch name.  Using `git checkout` with a commit hash ID, or with a name that is not a branch name, *detaches* the name `HEAD`, making it point directly to some commit.
- Using `git reset`, we can move the *current* branch to make it point to *any* commit, or if we're in detached HEAD mode, move the detached `HEAD` (i.e., the name `HEAD` itself) to point to any commit.  Doing this will abort any on-going merge, cherry-pick, or revert.  It does not (at least in modern Git) terminate an on-going rebase.  Git will remain in "detached HEAD" mode and your rebase will in fact still be going on.  Using `git rebase --continue` or `git rebase --skip` can drop a lot of commits at this point.
- `ORIG_HEAD` is like a cheap (in all senses) variant of the reflogs: it remembers *one* previous commit, from the last operation that moved your `HEAD` a lot.
- The real reflogs—there's one for `HEAD` plus one for each branch name—save *many* previous values.  Use `git reflog show` or `git log -g`, with branch name(s) or the name `HEAD` if you like, to show the reflog(s) of those branch(es) or of `HEAD`.
- `git rebase` works by:

  1. Listing the commits to be copied.
  2. Detaching HEAD, making it point to the commit after which the copies go.
  3. Cherry-picking<sup>1</sup> each commit to be copied, one at a time.  Each cherry-pick may have conflicts; if so, Git stops and makes you resolve the conflict.
  4. After the last cherry-pick finishes, *moving* the branch name to point to the last-copied commit.  This re-attaches `HEAD` and sets `ORIG_HEAD` to the previous value of the branch-name, which is also now in the branch's reflog.
- `git pull` does not do anything special.  It's meant to be a convenience short-cut.  I recommend avoiding it, but if you really are sure you're going to run `git merge` or `git rebase` right after a `git fetch`, that's what it will do for you: run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command.

---

<sup>1</sup>`git rebase --interactive` literally runs `git cherry-pick`; in modern Git, both are built into what Git calls, internally, the *sequencer*.  Some other rebase modes also literally use cherry-pick.  The default for a non-interactive rebase is actually a different path, using `git format-patch` and `git am` to copy the commits.  This path is slightly defective, in a sense, as it does not handle renames as well as the cherry-pick based method.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation; as always your answers give me a better understanding of git